# LibGDX InputProcessor doesn't work on android

Tags: java, android, input, keyboard, libgdx

Im making a text based game so of course, input is vital. On desktop i can simply poll key press events and this works fine. However it doesnt work with androids sot keyboard. I read somewhere that an InputProcessor can solve this issue. However, i have tried this and doesnt seem to work, heres my code:

```
 //in method called on Screen load
 Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(this);

//same class, later on
public boolean keyDown(int keycode) {
 //do stuff
 }
```

"stuff" happens on desktop but not on Android. However, i have noticed it works with some keyboard in the market and not others. Why is this? What can i do, any alternatives?

Answer (score 1):

Try making a textField and giving it focus.  Then catch the input and don't let it add to the text field.  Its a hack, but it might work

Comment: Okay this doesn't work on Andorid devices it seems. Why is this and how can i fix this. It's basically the same issue as before!

Comment: Right after experimenting, i found that symbols and numbers work perfect, but letters dont. Whats going on! ALso it works with HTC stock keyboard (Andoroid 2.3.3, Sense 2.1) but not on my other phone